# Did Vishal Bhardwaj want to make Shakespearean trilogy from the start?

Tags: haider, play-adaptation, maqbool, omkara

Vishal Bhardwaj made three films based on Shakespeare, [Maqbool (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maqbool) based on  [Macbeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth), [Omkara (2006)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omkara_(2006_film)) based on  [Othello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Othello) and [Haider (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haider_(film)) based on [Hamlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamlet); collectively know as Bhardwaj's Shakespearean trilogy.

But did Bhardwaj have the idea to make it like a trilogy from the start or did this only get considered later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that Vishal Bhardwaj is a big fan of Shakespeare. So clearly he must have wanted to turn them into movies and it seems he planned to make them a trilogy at least after the second film:

> "It will come because I have to complete my trilogy on Shakespeare but not in the near future," Bhardwaj said adding that he is yet to decide upon a specific play.

But he had to be sure, and when his first one was well accepted by people he must have gone to make others.

My theory is based on [this article from 2009](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/Vishal+Bhardwaj+wants+to+complete+trilogy+on+Shakespeare/1/67946.html).

And here are some more proofs:

> “My engagement with Shakespeare happened accidentally. In school, Shakespeare horrified me. Ninety per cent of directors want to make a gangster film, I was keen to go beyond the surface, say more than just killing,” Bhardwaj told an audience in Asia House this week.

[Original Article](http://www.hindustantimes.com/art-and-culture/400-years-of-shakespeare-vishal-bhardwaj-envoy-hail-bard-s-magic-of-words/story-lhdExZDeJox03sVQANfFGJ.html)

[Another article that suggests his love for The Bard](http://indianewshour.com/vishal-bhardwaj-there-is-no-writer-bigger-than-shakespeare/493/)